# Print To File sensitive data security issue

Tags: c#, security, printing

I'm working on a .NET check printing solution where security is obviously a huge concern.  The solution is using the System.Drawing.Printing namespace to handle printing.  The one exception to this is when using a printer that has secure memory.  Images of signatures are stored directly on the printer and the only way (from what I've found) to get them out is using PCL directly.  So to accommodate this my plan is to print to file, inject appropriate PCL to get the signature images to print, and then send the resulting PCL directly to the printer.

I've tested this approach successfully but I'd like to avoid having the printed file sit on the file system if even just for a moment.  Is there any way to redirect the the output to a MemoryStream or some other alternative way to make sure that file can't be read/tampered with?

Printing to file like so:

```
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "filename.prn";
printDoc.Print();
```

Comment: What kind of attack are you looking to circumvent?

Comment: I suspect that the client's complaint about this approach is going to be that someone could capture the .prn file and print their own copies of the check by sending it to a printer.